# Error while using jpcap java library

Tags: java, jpcap

I am using jpcap library to read network traffic and getting exception while executing the following code:

```
NetworkInterface[] devices = JpcapCaptor.getDeviceList();
```

Following is the error message:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: jpcap.JpcapCaptor.getDeviceList()[Ljpcap/NetworkInterface;
    at jpcap.JpcapCaptor.getDeviceList(Native Method)
    at nav.weka.first.JcapTest.main(JcapTest.java:16)

Is anything wrong with the jpcap.dll ???

Answer (score 0):

Your application is not finding the DLL. Check that it is on your PATH (not CLASSPATH).

Answer (score 0):

Did you install **winpcap**? http://www.winpcap.org/